# How to set XFCE indicator plugin clock format? the plugin not work properly

Tags: xfce, indicator

I like the clock show as HH:MM:SS. But I can't find a way to set XFCE indicator plug's clock as I wanted.
Does somebody have an idea?
I try to uninstall and reinstall the plugin. But there are no "Properties" in the right-click menu.

Comment: Right-click on the clock and choose `Poperties` from dropdown-menu.

Comment: No~There is no Poperties can be selected.

Comment: Be sure you have the proper plugin installed. The "Properties" should be listed on right-click. Otherwise, edit your question and complain your plugin is not working properly.

Comment: After remove/install the indicator plugin, the problem is still making trouble to me. There is no "Properties" showed on the right-click.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I've seen posts with other people having issues with the XFCE Panel Time plugin. I can't get the setting to stick.

- Make sure you are actually right-clicking on the applet in the panel.  Properties should be there. 
  You can remove it and add it back again.

  I had it go into a "half-sized" position on the 
  panel and had to click on one side of the plugin 
  area that I didn't have to with any other plugin. 
  It also was black on black so that was another guess where to click. I eventually got the right spot.
- Bring up a terminal. There are many ways to do 
  this:
- Use one from your menus.
- Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up a Run dialog.
  Type *xfce4-terminal*
  Click launch.
- Type *man strftime*
- The format code I think you want is: *%T

  HH:MM:SS*
- After you get properties in the "*Clock Options*"
  section choose "*custom*" in the "*Format section*".
- In the box below that type *%T*